# Trim audio file using python ffmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg, mp3, trim, cut

I am trying to simply input an audio file, trim the first 5 seconds and than output it into a directory. I am using jupyter notebook.
This is what i did:

```
import ffmpeg  

audio_input = ffmpeg.input('input.mp3')
audio_cut = audio_input.audio.filter('atrim', duration=5)
audio_output = ffmpeg.output(audio_cut, 'out.mp3')
```

I get no errors, but no results as well. I also noticed even if i enter a non-existent file name or path i still don't get any errors.

Comment: Did you try to convert the mp3 to raw PCM audio before cutting it ? I don't thing you can manipulate mp3 without decompressing it first.

Comment: I haven't tried that. Could you show me how it's done? I am pretty new to this. Or a reference would be helpful

Comment: The first thing you should do is to convert your file to a .wav file (if you don't have an application for that there are plenty of websites doing that online) and try again with `ffmpeg.input('input.wav)` instead to see if the problem is really there.

Answer (score 7):

Add a line of code: `ffmpeg.run(audio_output)`

```py
import ffmpeg  

audio_input = ffmpeg.input('input.mp3')
audio_cut = audio_input.audio.filter('atrim', duration=5)
audio_output = ffmpeg.output(audio_cut, 'out.mp3')
ffmpeg.run(audio_output)
```